# Kernel Module built doesn't include ccflags -y

Tags: module, kernel

***I was using https://github.com/croemheld/lkm-rootkit

with the following tree under pwd***

```
├── LICENSE

├── Makefile

├── README.md

└── src

    ├── core.c

    ├── getdents_hook.c

    ├── headers

    │   ├── core.h

    │   ├── getdents_hook.h

    │   ├── module_hiding.h

    │   ├── network_keylog.h

    │   ├── packet_hiding.h

    │   ├── port_knocking.h

    │   ├── privilege_escalation.h

    │   ├── server.h

    │   └── socket_hiding.h

    ├── include

    │   ├── headers

    │   │   └── utils.h -->this is where the error happens
 
    │   └── utils.c

    ├── libs

    │   ├── headers

    │   │   └── syscalltable.h

    │   └── syscalltable.c

    ├── module_hiding.c

    ├── network_keylog.c

    ├── packet_hiding.c

    ├── port_knocking.c

    ├── privilege_escalation.c

    ├── server.c

    └── socket_hiding.c


6 directories, 25 files
```

----------------------------------------------------------
with the following Makefile

```
# Module name
ROOTKIT     := rootkit

# Build
MODULEDIR   := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)
BUILDDIR    := $(MODULEDIR)/build
KERNELDIR   := $(MODULEDIR)/kernel

# Source files
SRCS_S      := src
LIBS_S      := src/libs
INCL_S      := src/include

# Header files
SRCS_H      := $(shell pwd)/$(SRCS_S)/headers
LIBS_H      := $(shell pwd)/$(LIBS_S)/headers
INCL_H      := $(shell pwd)/$(INCL_S)/headers


# Module
obj-m       := $(ROOTKIT).o

# Core
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/core.o

# Source
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/server.o
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/network_keylog.o
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/getdents_hook.o
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/socket_hiding.o
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/packet_hiding.o
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/port_knocking.o
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/privilege_escalation.o
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/module_hiding.o

# Libs
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/libs/syscalltable.o

# Include
$(ROOTKIT)-y    += src/include/utils.o

ccflags-y   := -I$(SRCS_H) -I$(LIBS_H) -I$(INCL_H)
subdir-ccflags-y    := -I$(SRCS_H) -I$(LIBS_H) -I$(INCL_H)
# Recipes
all:    print_file_vars
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules

load:
    insmod $(KERNELDIR)/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_reject_ipv4.ko
    insmod $(KERNELDIR)/net/ipv6/netfilter/nf_reject_ipv6.ko
    insmod rootkit.ko

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean
print_file_vars:
    $(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), $(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

---

***But when I sudo make,there is an error:***

```
 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-106-generic'

  CC [M]  /home/eric/Code/linux/module/lkm-rootkit/src/core.o
/home/eric/Code/linux/module/lkm-rootkit/src/core.c:1:19: fatal error: utils.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

***However ccflags-y has been set,include path has been add to ccflags-y,can someone help me,mercy***

Answer (score 0):

In `ccflags-y` for refer to the "current" directory (where your `Makefile` is located) use `$(src)` construction:

```
ccflags-y   := -I$(src)/src/headers
```

It is NOT correct to refer this directory using `$(shell pwd)`: when the module is built, the current directory refers to the **kernel build tree**, not to the directory with your `Makefile`.

---

Remember: your `Makefile` is parsed **twice**:

1. When you call `make` from the module's source directory.
2. When line `$(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules` is executed.

The first time your `Makefile` is processed in usual way, with `pwd` expanded to the **module's source directory**. That time Make executes `all` target and any other target it depends on. E.g. that time Make executes your `print_file_vars` target which prints value of `SRCS_H` variable and you find this variable to be correct.

The second time your `Makefile` is processed as a part on a larger Makefile with `pwd` expanded to the **kernel build directory**. Only that time variables `obj-m`, `ccflags-y` and other variables like `*-m` or `*-y` are used, and this is why you cannot use `pwd` for this variables.